# DevOps query unable to exclude work items that contain specific set of tags

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-query

I have 4 DevOps tags and 3 scenarios:

1. Work items that only contain 1 out of the 4 tags
2. Work items that contain all 4 tags
3. Work items that contain more than 1 but less than 4

I'm trying to build the following queries and having issues with 2-5:

1. return work items that contain all 4 tags (no issues)
2. return work items that contain tag 1 but do not contain tag 2 AND tag 3 AND tag 4
3. return work items that contain tag 2 but do not contain tag 1 AND tag 3 AND tag 4
4. return work items that contain tag 3 but do not contain tag 1 AND tag 2 AND tag 4
5. return work items that contain tag 4 but do not contain tag 1 AND tag 2 AND tag 3

**Query 1**
(successful - only returns items that contain all 4 tags)

Contains Tag 1
And Contains Tag 2
And Contains Tag 3
And Contains Tag 4
(clauses are grouped)

However, when I try the opposite it is also excluding work items that only contain 2 of the tags e.g., work items that only contain Tag 1 and Tag 3. The query seems to be treating them as ‘or’ instead of ‘and’ and I can’t figure out where I’m going wrong:

**Query 2**

Does not Contain Tag 2
AND Does not Contain Tag 3
AND Does not Contain Tag 4
(clauses are grouped)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Cordelle

UDPATE WITH USER SCREENSHOTS:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8gdk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmX5A.png)

Answer (score 0):

It works. **All tags**:
[image]

**contain tag 1 but do not contain tag 2 AND tag 3 AND tag 4**

[image]

**contain tag 2 but do not contain tag 1 AND tag 3 AND tag 4**

[image]

**or more complex query**

[image]

**Additional one:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for testing that and providing your reply Shamrai - I appreciate your time.  I've added a couple screenshots to my original post if you want to take a look at my actual query. I think I'm doing what you did but I still seem to be unable to return work items that only contain some, not all of the tags.  I will try to replicate the scenarios you built and see I have a different outcome.  If you have any other suggestions after looking at my screenshots, please let me know!

Comment: I just repro'd your scenario and realized that your query is behaving the same as mine.  In query 'contain tag 1 but do not contain tag 2 AND tag 3 AND tag 4' wouldn't you expect it to return tasks #2, #5, AND #4? My problem is that I want a way to return task 4 (only exclude if it contains all 3 tags). What do you think?

Comment: @Cordelle your task is too complex for a work item query... that may be like this: `Contains TAG1 ((AND does not Contain TAG2 AND does not Contain TAG3) (OR does not Contain TAG2 AND does not Contain TAG4)(OR does not Contain TAG3 AND does not Contain TAG4))`. Check my last screenshot.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank you very much for your time. I will try that approach and might also ask if a new tag can be created to help me differentiate between work items that contain 'All' vs. everything else.  Thanks again!